# flask-wtf forms SelectMultipleField not allowing multiple selection

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

This is the Category.py to create fields

```
class CategoryForms(FlaskForm):
   cat_choices = [('sport', 'sport'),('music',music')]
   categories = SelectedMultipleField('Categories' choices = cat_choices)
   submit=SubmitField('Lets Go!')
```

This is the Category.html that displays the fields

```
<form action ='' method='Post'>
    {{form.hidden_tag}}
    <p>
         {{form.categories.label}}
         {{form.categories)row=3 multiple=True}
    </p>
    <p>
         {{form.submit()}}
    </p>
<form>
```

The routes.py

```
@app('category, methods['GET','POST'])
def category():
    form = CategoryForms()
    if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_submitted():
           result = form.categories.data
           return render_template('cat-request.html', result=result)
     return render_template('category.html', title='Category', form = form)
```

My issue are:

1) The select options only allow for one section and not multiple.
2) When getting the user input, I did a for loop but nothing displays. Is this the right approach? Like below:

in the cat-request.html file

```
{% for value in result %}
    {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're passing a variable named `result` to the html, but the html is using a variable named `results`.  The two names don't match.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks that helped the display. But I only get 1 option. How can I select multiple options? It only allows me to select 1 yet I have created a selectmultiplefield

Comment: Same issue. Can only select 1 option

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you after this, but once rendered SelectMultipleField, in order to select multiple fields in a browser view, you need to press ctrl or shift.
Otherwise just once option is selected. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFd3.png)